# Creating own environment for writing partial oxidation and reduction reactions

Tags: environments, chemistry

I was wondering if it is posssible to write my own environment for writing redox equations in form of:

O: ...

R: ...

*___________________________*

S: ...

O stands for oxidation, R for reduction and S for the summary equation. Also, there is line that should separate O and R from S.

I have never written any environment in LaTeX, so could anyone just help me start? I've seen that there are some packages that are about chemistry, but none help me about this problem.

Comment: Can you provide the code for a starter answer which includes an example of what might go into each of the slots? It's pretty easy to create your own custom environment and there are various ways to do it, but I have no idea what kind of content you're working with.

Comment: Just in case, check the [`chemmacros`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros) package. Perhaps it has an environment or option that does what you need so you don’t need to make everything from scratch if you need this for a single use!

Comment: I have looked into the package, but couldn't find anything that fits what I need. I would like to make an environment, since I would use it multiple times. Unfortunantely, I have no code because don't know how to start.

Comment: Please have a look hiere: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros#New_environments (and elsewhere in said book ; )

Comment: If you don't want three separate environments for O, R, S, then you should just define a command with 3 parameters.

Answer (score 1):

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\orseq}[3]{%
    % #1 = O
    % #2 = R
    % #3 = S
    O: #1
    
    R: #2
    
    \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
    
    S: #3
}

\begin{document}

\orseq{foo}{bar}{foobar}

\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]