# Redox half-reactions environment

Tags: chemistry, chemmacros

Can someone help me write environment for redox half-reactions with exact alignment shown in the photo? Also, how to make that the lenght of the line is determined by the length of the longest equation? Thanks.

[image]

**EDIT:** This is what I got so far

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

\begin{reactions*}
    &O:& &Hg_2^{2+}\aq{} + 4 NH3\aq{} + 4 NO3^-\aq{} -> 2 HgNH2NO3\sld{} + 2 NH4NO3\aq{} + 2 \el\\
    &R:& &Hg_2^{2+}\aq{} + 2 \el -> 2 Hg\sld{}\\
    &S:& &Hg_2^{2+}\aq{} + 2 NH3\aq{} + 2 NO3^-\aq{} <=> Hg\sld{} + HgNH2NO3\sld{} + NH4NO3\aq{}
\end{reactions*}

\end{document}
```

Now, how to add that the lenght of the line (located evenly between the second and the third equation) is determined by the length of the longest equation?

**EDIT 2:** Updated the code so it can be easily compiled.

Comment: Is this a continuation of your [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/690838/270231)?

Comment: Do not aks multiple questions at once and also please provide some code to start with since there are different packages to typeset chemical reactions. Please help us help you and post what you tried so far. If this is a follow-up question, please at least provide a link to the other question and clarify what should be improved.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as mentioned in a comment, this seems to be a follow-up of a previously closed question.

Comment: If I go to the effort of going through both questions, I think I might be able to figure out what you're trying to do.  Please put that effort into this question.  Provide the code you have so far, the result it gives, and how you'd like to change it.

Comment: I just edited the question and have shown what I got so far.

Comment: @crvenikupus Please don't just post a code fragment. Always make a small, but compilable test document, including a class and the necessary packages.

Comment: Sorry. I have edited it.